# Detect movement or shaking in a windows 8 device

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, accelerometer, tablet

In Windows 8 Metro - given that it is intended to be used on a tablet, is it possible to detect if the device has been shaken or moved?

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700412.aspx) article doesn't seem to cover device movement.

If this is possible then are there any online tutorials or code snippets available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [acceleromator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br225687.aspx).  [Example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Accelerometer-Sensor-Sample-22982671).

```
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.Devices.Sensors;

namespace AccelerometerCS
{

    partial class BlankPage
    {
        // Sensor and dispatcher variables
        private Accelerometer _accelerometer;

        // This event handler writes the current accelerometer reading to 
        // the three acceleration text blocks on the app's main page.

        private void ReadingChanged(object sender, AccelerometerReadingChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, (s, a) =>
            {
                AccelerometerReading reading = (a.Context as AccelerometerReadingChangedEventArgs).Reading;
                txtXAxis.Text = String.Format("{0,5:0.00}", reading.AccelerationX);
                txtYAxis.Text = String.Format("{0,5:0.00}", reading.AccelerationY);
                txtZAxis.Text = String.Format("{0,5:0.00}", reading.AccelerationZ);

            }, this, e);
        }

        public BlankPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _accelerometer = Accelerometer.GetDefault();

            if (_accelerometer != null)
            {
                // Establish the report interval
                uint minReportInterval = _accelerometer.MinimumReportInterval;
                uint reportInterval = minReportInterval > 16 ? minReportInterval : 16;
                _accelerometer.ReportInterval = reportInterval;

                // Assign an event handler for the reading-changed event
                _accelerometer.ReadingChanged += new TypedEventHandler<Accelerometer, AccelerometerReadingChangedEventArgs>(ReadingChanged);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And note that there's specifically a Shaken event on the accelerometer, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.sensors.accelerometer.shaken.aspx.

Comment: Not working for Windows Phone 8 devices : "The accelerometer sensor does not raise the Shaken event on the Windows Phone 8 platform. If you add an event handler for the Shaken event in your Windows Phone 8 app, no error is raised, but the code in the event handler won’t run."

Comment: @Filimindji This question is explicitly about Windows 8, _not_ Windows Phone 8